# Product of two periodic functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am searching necessary and sufficient condition for two periodical functions $f$ and $g$ so that product $fg$ is a periodic function. Clearly if periods of $f$ and $g$ are integral multiple of each other then $fg$ is a periodical function with a period  as l.c.m. of periods of $f$ and $g.$ Please give me necessary and sufficient condition when $fg$ is periodic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can have two "incompatible" periods for $f$ and $g$, such as $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$, and yet have $fg$ with nice period.

Comment: so what can we say about above question?

Comment: I don't think you can say very much about the above question, in general.

Comment: Certainly when $f$ and $g$ have periods whose ratio is rational, then $fg$ is periodic. When the ratio is irrational, usually $fg$ is not periodic but sometimes it is.  This is comment material, since it is not particularly satisfactory as an answer, even with detailed example!

Comment: @AndréNicolas   can we say some thing about continuous functions?

Comment: @AndréNicolas if possible write with example in answers so that it may be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

This question is discussed here https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1256835192